# Deploying Spring Boot App in Docker container without auto starting Tomcat

Tags: docker, tomcat, kubernetes

I was under the impression that including the line

```
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

to the Dockerfile would be what triggers the Tomcat server to start.
I've removed that line but it still starts the server on deployment. I basically want to add the catalina.sh run and include CATALINA_OPTS all in a Kubernetes deployment to handle this stuff, but Tomcat still auto starts up when I deploy to a container.

Comment: Without knowing what docker image you're using, and any commands that came before the `CMD`, it's impossible to answer your question. That said, you can absolutely set `CATALINA_OPTS` using the `env:` key in the `PodSpec`'s `container`, and can even do so across all such `Deployment`s via [`envFrom.configMapKeyRef`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#envvarsource-v1-core)

Answer (score 0):

Docker image usually has an entry point or a command already.

If you create your custom image based on another image from a registry, which is a common case, you can override base image entry point by specifying the `ENTRYPOINT` or the `CMD` directive.

If you omit the entry point in your docker file, it will be *inherited from the base image*.

Consider reading [Dockerfile: ENTRYPOINT vs CMD](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/) article to have a better understanding of how it works.